# history.go(-1) function not refreshing server side controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using a dropdown, a devexpress grid view and a button on my page.

My gropdown contains the months in the format MM/YYYY, and on dropdown's selection change the data binds in the grid view.

the functionality of button is to go on previous page as same as back button of browser.

Now, my prob is that if i select any month and then select another month, the data changes.
but now when i click on back button having onclick ="history.go(-1)", changes the data on the grid view but the month in the dropdown remains the same.

For example:

Suppose, first i have month selected as 02/2010
At this time the data in grid view is for exapmle 01234

now when i select month 03/2010
the data in grid changes to 56789

now when i click on back button, then data in grid changes to 01234 but the month in dropdown remains to 03/2010.

Please help me for this..

Thanks in advance for all who will give solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side web page should have a page-timeout. so that browser will get contents back from the web server again instead of showing it from history. Or browser might show the page as content Expired, please refresh.

Comment: thanks for your answer but if i do that then how could i maintain the previous values, means it can go to n level i.e suppose i select first 02/2010 then 03/2010 then 05/2010, then i want it to go back in opposite manner. page time out will bring the content back to original form

Comment: can u please tell me that how can i do this, i.e page-time out

Comment: this.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.nocache);  user will press f5 intelligent browser will fill the form again (if user has set so.. for ex, safari browser in my iphone), otherwise you got to maintain in the session in memory..

Comment: http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webapps/settingoutputcachelocation.aspx   -----    http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/04/disable-browser-back-button-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

The browser is caching your page. You should add a session tracker or something to your page and LINK back, (aka not JS)